# Using the Kramers-Kronig (Hilbert) transform in Python

Tags: python, scipy, integration, least-squares, sympy

I am trying to use the Kramers-Kronig algorithm to transform the real and imaginary contributions to the anomalous scattering factor from a diffraction anomalous fine structure (DAFS) experiment.

I have fit a smooth curve to my experimental data using the `lmfit` package, and the following function:

```
def intensity(en, phi, beta, I0=1, slope=0, Ioff=0, fprime=-1, fsec=1):
    costerm = np.cos(phi) + beta*fprime
    sinterm = np.sin(phi) + beta*fsec
    return I0 * (costerm**2 + sinterm**2) + slope*en + Ioff
```

I have found minimised values of the listed parameters in the function and used them to calculate an initial guess for `f'` according to:

```
def f1_guess(f2, I, I0, phi, beta, Ioff):
    f1_guess = (1/beta) * (np.sqrt(((I-Ioff)/I0) - (math.sin(phi)+(beta*f2))) - math.cos(phi)) 
    return f1_guess
```

I am now trying to use the Kramers-Kronig relation to transform this initial `f'` guess to an `f"` that can then be put back into the `lmfit` process to model the intensity, and subsequently calculate the fine structure. I have tried a few things, including the `scipy.fftpack`, as well as the `scipy.integrate` and `sympy.integrate` packages.

The issue I am facing is that I need to calculate the KK transform over a finite energy range, I.E. instead of the following:

[image]

I should do something more like the function below, by taking out the known atomic lineshape f"a(E) and integrating over my experimental energy range:

[image]

However, I am struggling to distinguish between `E'` and `E` (or `omega'` and `omega`) - I don't know how they are different from each other - and so I am unsure of how to specify these values in script format in such a way that I can accurately evaluate this integral.

Does anyone know how I might be able to transfer my `f'` to `f"`, and iterate through my lmfit model until the 4 parameters (`I0`, `Ioff`, `beta`, `phi`) and the `f"/f'` fine structure functions stabilise?

Any help would be much appreciated, and also happy to link any relevant papers I have been reading on the topic if desired.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this would resolve your issue, but Python (SciPy) has a Hilbert transform functionality (see [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.hilbert.html)).
Being that the [Hilbert transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_transform) is the core for the Kramers-Kronig relations (with some additional scaling by a constant), perhaps this can be useful to you.